# sklearn - Cannot call inverse_transform of MultiLabelBinarizer right away

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn

After instanciating a `MultiLabelBinarizer`, I need its `inverse_transform` method for a matrix that I built elsewhere.
Unfortunately,

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer(classes=['a', 'b', 'c'])

A = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]])
y = mlb.inverse_transform(A)
```

yields `AttributeError: 'MultiLabelBinarizer' object has no attribute 'classes_'`

I noticed that if I add this line after the instanciation of `mlb`,

```
mlb.fit_transform([(c,) for c in ['a', 'b', 'c']])
```

the error disappears. I'm guessing this is because `fit_transform` sets the value of the `classes_` attribute, but I would expect it to be done at instanciation, since I'm providing a `classes` parameter.

I'm using sklearn version 0.17.1 and python 2.7.6.
Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to set the attribute `classes_` within the instance of `MultiLabelBinarizer`, you can also do a quick hack like this:

```
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer().fit(['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Because like marmouset said, only `fit` and `fit_transorm` seems to fit the `classes_`attribute. Furthermore, the documentation of scikit-learn.org http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html explicitly specify that the method `fit` can return an instance of `MultiLabelBinarizer`.

```
def fit(self, y):
    """Fit the label sets binarizer, storing `classes_`
    Parameters
    ----------
    y : iterable of iterables
        A set of labels (any orderable and hashable object) for each
        sample. If the `classes` parameter is set, `y` will not be
        iterated.
    Returns
    -------
    self : returns this MultiLabelBinarizer instance
    """
```

Answer (score 2):

it appears to be implemented as is https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/51a765a/sklearn/preprocessing/label.py#L636, .fit is the only method that defines the classes_ attribute. 
 classes_ is not defined as a copy of classes in the constructor, and considering the definition given in the comment, it wasn't meant to be as such; you could warn the author.

```
class MultiLabelBinarizer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    """Transform between iterable of iterables and a multilabel format
    Although a list of sets or tuples is a very intuitive format for multilabel
    data, it is unwieldy to process. This transformer converts between this
    intuitive format and the supported multilabel format: a (samples x classes)
    binary matrix indicating the presence of a class label.
    Parameters
    ----------
    classes : array-like of shape [n_classes] (optional)
        Indicates an ordering for the class labels
    sparse_output : boolean (default: False),
        Set to true if output binary array is desired in CSR sparse format
    Attributes
    ----------
    classes_ : array of labels
        A copy of the `classes` parameter where provided,
        or otherwise, the sorted set of classes found when fitting.
```